# How to define a sequence of functions with RcppGSL?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I would like to do a 2-dimentional spline interpolation. Since GSL library does not have a multi-dimentional function ready to use, I think I could use two-step interpolation. That is, I interpolate along first dimension conditional on a grid of values of the second dimension, and then interpolate along the second dimension. In R, I can easily create a list of spline functions that can bridge the two steps. For example, I have a vector of `x` and `y`, and the corresponding matrix of `z = f(x,y)`. Now I want to interpolate `f(x0,y0)` at values of `x0` and `y0`.

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 3:8
z <- matrix(rnorm(length(x)*length(y)), length(x), length(y))
x0 <- 2.2; y0 <- 4.5

# Create a sequence of spline functions conditional on y
spl.list <- vector("list", length(y))
for(i in 1:length(y)){
    spl.list[[i]] <- splinefun(x, z[,i], "natural")
}
# The function values at (x0, y).
intp1 <- sapply(1:length(y), function(i) spl.list[[i]](x0) )
# Create the spline function along y.
intp2.spl <- splinefun(y, intp1, "natural")
intp2.spl(y0)
```

I'm trying to achieve the similar goal with RcppGSL. I'm using `gsl_spline` from GSL. However, the issue is that I'm not aware of anything in RcppGSL that can stores a sequence of functions, i.e., something like `spl.list` in the R code above. I tried `List`, but it is apparently not the right thing. The code below is my univariate interpolation function in RcppGSL.

```
src <- '
#include <RcppGSL.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_spline.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppGSL)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double my_fn(NumericVector x, NumericVector y, double x0){
    int nx = x.length();
    gsl_interp_accel *accP  = gsl_interp_accel_alloc();
    gsl_spline *spline  = gsl_spline_alloc( gsl_interp_cspline , nx );
    gsl_spline_init( spline, x.begin(), y.begin(), nx);

    double out = gsl_spline_eval(spline, x0, accP);
    gsl_interp_accel_free (accP);
    gsl_spline_free (spline);
    return(out);
}
'
sourceCpp(code = src)
```

Anyone has some thought of how to create a sequence of functions in RcppGSL? Or other alternatives to get the 2-dimensional spline interpolation with RcppGSL?